# IW and IWCONFIG reveals different wireless interface results

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, vmware

I am using VMWare Fusion with Ubuntu 14.04 as guest system upon the OSX host system.

The question is that when I plugged in the USB Wifi adapter (TP Link WN725N in my case), The commands `iwconfig`, `ifconfig`, and `ip` could reveal the `wlan0` wireless interface, but the `iw dev` has no result coming out.

How can I make the wireless interface detected by the `iw`?